# Show/Hide a button based on SQL query result

Tags: php, sql

Hi i'm trying to hide a button if the count of rows with a certain value id in this case DeckID are Greater than 40.

My code so far is as below:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cards WHERE DeckID=$deck";
$result3 = $link->query($sql3) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3) <= 40){
    ?> 
    <form action='includes/addtodeck.php' method='get'>
      <input type='hidden' name='un' value='<?php echo$row["id_unique"] ?>' />
      <button value='<?php echo $deck ?>' name='DID'>Add to deck</button>
    </form>
    <hr align='left' width='80%'>
    <?php
} else {
    echo "Deck is full <br><br>";
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: _Warning_ - you can not mix `mysqli` and `mysql`. The `mysql` extension is deprecated, use `mysqli` extension instead. You are vulnerable to SQL injection. Always use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this solution, I have not used SQL injection. But it will be great if you use SQL injection. I just mentioned solution to your code without SQL injection.

```
$sql3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM movies";
$result3 = $link->query($sql3) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
if($rows['count'] <= 40){
    echo "Deck is not full";
}else{
    echo"Deck is full <br><br>";
}
```

In above code, I have used alias(count) in SQL. `mysqli_fetch_array($result3)` this return data in array format. so you have to check values from array Ex. `$row['count']`.

Comment: This worked great, I'm fairly new to php/sql, I'm working on a proof of concept, I'll be looking into more secure routes for my code once I have a skeleton built, Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you mixed up your code.
Here I give you full example to start up from `connection` until the form. (Using Procedural SQL connection with `mysqli`)

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "username", "password", "database_name");

$deck = mysqli_real_escape_string($deck);   //Prevent SQL Injection at somepoint by escaping string
$q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM cards WHERE DeckID = '{$desk}'"); //Select you table
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($q); //Fetch as array or you may use fetch_assoc and fetch_object as well.

if(count($row) <= 40){ //other than count, you may use mysqli_num_rows($q)
?> 
    <form action='includes/addtodeck.php' method='get'>
        <input type='hidden' name='un' value='<?php echo $row["id_unique"] ?>'>
        <button value='<?php echo $deck ?>' name='DID'>Add to deck</button>
    </form>
    <hr align='left' width='80%'>
<?php
}else{
    echo"Deck is full <br><br>";
}
```

Like other said, the above code are not 100% secured on SQL injection, you might want to use Data Binding for best performance and secure.

As you can see, I remove the `COUNT(*)` because you want to use the `$row["id_unique"]` in your form, so have to select all/specific column rather than just count it.

Comment: I'm fairly new to php/sql, I'm working on a proof of concept, I'll be looking into more secure routes for my code once I have a skeleton built, Thank you for the help and advice ^_^